# Adding attachment to Approval in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to write an approval workflow in Power Automate where it adds the attachments from a SharePoint list. I have followed a number of examples and they all seem to say that once I have reached the point 'append to array variable' when I write the value JSON in dynamic content there should be a section called 'Get attachment content' and within that I need select the AttachmentContent value. However although 'Get Attachments' section is available there is no 'get Attachment content' section so I can't select the value.
Wonder if anyone has any ideas why that is not appearing I have included an image of the flow so far. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Append to array variable` action needs to be moved up into your `Apply to each`

[image]